# How to take average first 10 150 rows of column and use average value as first value of column and second value of column start from row 151

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i am trying to calculate average of first 150 rows of column and use average value as first value of column and row 151 as second row of column and so on...is there any package in python that can solve this problem.

Note: only need to take average of first 150 rows  other rows remains same as original dataframe.

Here is my data and desired output:

```
print (df)
      col2  desired_output
0   14.375       14.261111
1   14.350       14.175000
2   14.300       14.125000
3   14.350       14.150000
4   14.300       13.974000
5   14.225       14.074000
6   14.175       14.099000
7   14.150       13.949000
8   14.125       13.899000
9   14.175       13.849000
10  14.125       13.749000
11  14.150       13.774000
12  13.974             NaN
13  14.074             NaN
14  14.099             NaN
15  13.949             NaN
16  13.899             NaN
17  13.849             NaN
18  13.749             NaN
19  13.774             NaN
```

in this example data i took mean of first 9 values of col2 and placed as first value of desired_output

Comment: Can you add some sample data for average `3` rows with expected output?

Comment: @ jezrael  please check data

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot copy data, because pictures, is possible paste data in text?

Comment: please check your email, just now i sent you data in your mail. thanks

Comment: Answer was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and set first value of column to `mean` with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for count first `N` values:

```
N = 9
df['new'] = df['col2'].shift(-N+1)
df.loc[0, 'new'] = df.iloc[:N, df.columns.get_loc('col2')].mean()

print (df)
      col2  desired_output        new
0   14.375       14.261111  14.261111
1   14.350       14.175000  14.175000
2   14.300       14.125000  14.125000
3   14.350       14.150000  14.150000
4   14.300       13.974000  13.974000
5   14.225       14.074000  14.074000
6   14.175       14.099000  14.099000
7   14.150       13.949000  13.949000
8   14.125       13.899000  13.899000
9   14.175       13.849000  13.849000
10  14.125       13.749000  13.749000
11  14.150       13.774000  13.774000
12  13.974             NaN        NaN
13  14.074             NaN        NaN
14  14.099             NaN        NaN
15  13.949             NaN        NaN
16  13.899             NaN        NaN
17  13.849             NaN        NaN
18  13.749             NaN        NaN
19  13.774             NaN        NaN
```